# Replacing Query output string when the count is less than 3

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Given the reference table below:

```
Date        Location
11/29/2018  Office A
11/29/2018  Office B
11/27/2018  Office C
11/27/2018  Office A
11/27/2018  Office A
11/24/2018  Office C
11/24/2018  Office C
11/11/2018  Office C
11/11/2018  Office B
11/2/2018   Office C
```

Is it possible to change the output of the query based on its sum of the count of the location column?

The expected output is the following:

```
Date        Location    Count
11/29/2018  Office A    1
11/29/2018      -       1
11/27/2018  Office C    1
11/27/2018  Office A    2
11/24/2018  Office C    2
11/11/2018  Office C    1
11/11/2018      -       1
11/2/2018   Office C    1
```

The expected output converts "Office B" Location into an empty string because the sum of the count is less than 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your raw data were in A1:B, this QUERY should produce what you want:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:A,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B,B2:B)<3,"-",B2:B)},"Select Col1, Col2, COUNT(Col2) Where Col1 Is Not Null Group By Col1, Col2 Order By Col1 Desc Label Col1 'Date', Col2 'Location'"))`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Is it possible to put the if and count if outside of the query function? I was combining{} 2 query functions to pull from two different sheets and wondering if that would still work

Comment: It's difficult to envision what you mean without seeing your data. However, if you just mean you're trying to get the same information from two sheets stacked into one, the portion in curly brackets would look similar to this (see next comment, noticing the double curly brackets front and back):

Comment: {{Sheet1!A2:A,IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!B2:B)<3,"-",Sheet1!B2:B)};{Sheet2!A2:A,IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B2:B,Sheet2!B2:B)<3,"-",Sheet2!B2:B)}}

Comment: There are other ways, but if you just have two sheets, that's one of the more straightforward approaches.

Comment: Tried that but It would need to add the count of the B2 on Sheet 1 and the count of B2 on Sheet 2 and their sum is less than 3.

Comment: Again, I know that what you are saying makes sense to you, because you can see what your sheets and data, and you know what you expect. But from "out here," it's difficult (even for a reasonably smart guy who does this for a living) to understand what you mean without being able to see the sheet and data myself. Please feel free to share a link to the sheet or a copy of it, and I will take another look for you.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. 

Here is a spreadsheet link with what I'm trying to do. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a4zcApy-HOz6MGgY-2dQOvrvlu6l3Zi_rABcO2kGHR8/edit?usp=sharing

Basically Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are the data. Sheet 3 is where its all combined. But when they are combined they both have different countif statements for the OFFICE Column. Meaning that the office count is actually greater than 3 when the data is combined, but its still counted as less than three and cleared

Comment: I can now access your sheet. However, you've got a column here, "Type," which was not part of your original post; so it is still unclear what you want in the end, on Sheet 3. Please delete the formulas on Sheet 3 and manually type in what you want the final result to look like. This is the best way for me or anyone else to understand how to help you.

Comment: Made a Sheet 4 with no formula, just the expected output. "Type" is what's being counted in the final product. It's not really important to what I'm trying to ask but this table is closer to the final product. I highlighted the main difference between sheet 3 and 4 in yellow (The inclusion of Office B in sheet 4). The formula I'm looking for combines data from both sheets and counts the number offices. If the office count is < 3, it replaces it with a "-". The formula you gave only counts the offices per sheet.

Comment: So when they are combined, in the example in sheet 3, Office B is still replaced by "-" since it is counting the offices separately rather than combined. To be further clarify, Sheet 1 has 2 "Office B" and Sheet 2 has 2 "Office B". Separately they are less than 3 so they get replaced by "-". But when I combine them in sheet 3 or 4, they don't add the number of "Office B" which are now 4, meaning they don't need to replaced by "-" anymore. Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: It looks like you've got a Sheet5 in place now that is doing what I assume you want it to. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Figured it out with your help! It didn't work the first time because all of the ranges needed to be the same lengths.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end.